# Sum one column to get largest number subject to a constraint in another column

Tags: python, pandas

[image]I have a dataframe with two columns:

Hours        Revenue
1             £50
1             £45
1             £101
1             £98
2             £175
1             £10
3             £123
3.5           £95

I wish to find the largest sum of the revenue column subject to the hours being less than 5 say.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I have added a picture but the hours column ranges from 0.5 to 18

Comment: Please define: "largest sum of the revenue column".

Comment: So If I had data = {'Hour': [1,2,3],'Revenue': [10,90,80]} if I had an hour constraint of 2 my max would be 90, if it was 1 it would be ten if it was 3 it would 100, a sum of the first two entries.

Answer (score 0):

**If I don't misunderstood your requirements**, then you can try like this way-

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Hour': [1,1,1,1,2,1,3,3.5],'Revenue': ['£50','£45','£101','£98','£175','£10','£123','£95']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Revenue'] = df['Revenue'].str[1:].astype(int)
hour_group = df.groupby('Hour').sum().reset_index()
res = hour_group[hour_group['Hour'] < 5.0]
#print(hour_group)
print(res)
```